# Angularjsjs form required field don't validate on load

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a form text field it is required but its initial value is an empty string, so when I load the form the controller validates the form field and marks it as error, I want on the initial load not to validate the form field only after an onblur event.

```
<input data-ng-model="MyCtrl.opportunity.company" type="text" class="form-control" name="company" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" required />
```

And here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/petran/Lvc0u55v/725/

I know I can call $setValidity on controller I am looking for a more elegant solution if there is exist.

Answer (score 0):

Add this statement to ng-class statement:

```
 ...&& addOpportunityForm.company.$dirty...
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Without, your answer might get flagged "low quality" and eventually removed.

Comment: This statement is for checking that input was changed once. After being changed once, $dirty flag is true.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $pristine for validation tool in AngularJS. This will allow the funtion to wait until the input field has been changed before testing the condition. You can learn more about form states here: [Angular Form States](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp)